# Assigning member function to a member variable in Swift

Tags: swift, function, functional-programming

Is it possible, or does the function need to be declared `static` or `class`?

```
class SimManager {
    var particleSimulation: (inout Particle, Float) -> Void = updateParticles

    func updateParticles(inout p: Particle, deltaT: Float) -> Void {
       ...
    }
}
```

Gives the compiler error:

> SimManager.swift:36:63: Cannot convert value of type 'SimManager -> (inout Particle, deltaT: Float) -> Void' to specified type '(inout Particle, Float) -> Void'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the initialization of `particleSimulation` to the designated initializer of the class.

```
class SimManager {
  var particleSimulation: ((inout Particle, Float) -> Void)!

  func updateParticles(inout p: Particle, deltaT: Float) -> Void {
  }

  init() {
    self.particleSimulation = updateParticles
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. The ugliness below also works in init() to avoid the need to declare it as an implicitly unwrapped optional:
        
`particleSimulation = {(inout p: Particle, deltaT: Float) -> Void in }`

`particleSimulation = updateParticles`

This function gets called 5000+ times per frame so is very performance critical. Because it's an alias to the type `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<WrappedType>` there probably is some overhead, but not sure. I also declared the function final in order to avoid Dynamic Dispatch overhead.